# Problem parsing Google weather data only for Paris

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser, google-weather-api

I have created an app for weather reports by using this http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=paris. It works well for all cities except Paris.

In my app I have a text field; if I type "Sydney", it will show the weather in Sydney,
but if I type "Paris", it gives an error: `NSXMLParserErrorDomain error:9`. I don't know what it means. What could be the error? Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you could post some of your code?

Comment: Careful with using the Google weather API.  It's undocumented and is liable to change at any time, thus breaking your app.

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it has encountered an illegal character:
NSXMLParserInvalidCharacterError = 9,

Make sure you correctly parse this as UTF-8

Comment: but that app is working well for all cities.. i used cities like london,sydney,ooty,trichy,delhi.. it is working well for this cities but it is not working only for paris...

Comment: @aravindhanarvi: "Paris, Île-de-France" contains characters you're not likely to find in "London", "New Delhi, Delhi", etc.

Comment: Paris is defined in the feed as ""Paris, Île-de-France" -- do the other cities' data contain UTF-8 characters like "Î"?

Comment: @wooble: i am referring <postal_code data="paris"/>.. and <postal_code data="delhi"/> like that..

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi: I suggest you actually read the contents of the link you posted. The parser needs to be able to read the whole thing, and since it's utf-8 encoded you can't treat it like it's ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that XML you are parsing contains some UTF-8 characters, but XML does not have proper XML declaration for UTF-8.

Make sure you configure your parser correctly.